# How to look inside the string from previous regex result

Tags: python, regex

REGEX:
I have text in file as below and i am trying to get the part inside quotes from the line starts with user_id.

```
DECLARE
   user_id    VARCHAR(1)  := 'ITSME'; -- 
BEGIN
 SELECT * FROM XXX WHERE user_id='ITSME';
```

I can get full user_id line from below regex.

Code i tried to get the first part

```
(?i)user_id.*(?i)VARCHAR.*:=.*;
```

I am trying for second part where i can get the string inside quotes from the above output.

I tried below part and i am able to get the output i want.

```
(?:(?i)user_id\s*(?i)VARCHAR.*\s*:=\s*')(.*)(?:'.*;)
```

But is there a way to rewrite above without out ?:
Like

```
Look for string  insides quotes IN ((?i)user_id.*(?i)VARCHAR.*:=.*;) -- this first part regex output
```

PYTHON:

```
x = re.findall('''(?:(?i)user_id\s*(?i)VARCHAR.*\s*:=\s*')(.*)(?:'.*;)''', content)
print (x)
```

So i tried to display the output in python using above and it is displaying the result i want.

Is there a simple way to rewrite the regex without `?:`

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: I am planning to use this in Python. I tried the above part and it is displaying in Python without any issue

Comment: Use `r"user_id.*:=\s*'([^']+)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
^\s*user_id(?=.*VARCHAR).+?'([^']+)'
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/Uc5FfX/1/).

Comment: thank jan. so whatever you keep in () at last will be the output. do you know why my answer in python is throwing me the warning "DeprecationWarning: Flags not at the start of the expression", but yours is not throwing any warning.

Comment: Also why i am getting quotes and brackets ['ITSME'] in python IDLE output. can we remove them ?